# How do the statistical calculation according to X people?

Tags: statistics

It's common to read something like "for 10 people, 5 prefer something" (**5 people this total of 10 people**).
Eg: `8 in 10 people over 50 years old use the Internet`
Suppose I have a total group of 29 people and 23 people in this group like apple, as we reduce this analysis to "every 10 people, X people like apple"? Is there any formula?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what your question is with the grammatical mistakes in your post.  "How does that calculation?"  Do you mean to ask "how did they get the ratio $5:10$?"  Or do you mean to ask "how can I mathematically represent this information?"  The answer to the first is that they gathered data and inferred a pattern.  The answer to the second is that you can represent ratios as fractions.  "8 in 10 people..." $\Leftrightarrow$ "$\frac{8}{10} = 0.8 = 80\%$ of people..."

Comment: Sorry, I speak Portuguese and it's really difficult to express without a calculation to demonstrate show what I'm asking.

Comment: $\frac{23}{29} = \frac{230/29}{10} = \frac{7.93103}{10}$ so it's $7.93103$ out of $10$ people for your example. Do you see how to do it in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your edit you asked: "Suppose I have a total group of 29 people and 23 people in this group like apple, as we reduce this analysis to "every 10 people, X people like apple"? Is there any formula?"

To understand the answer, you need to first understand what a representation of data in this way actually means.  When we say "23 people out of 29 like apples", that is a **ratio** or number of people who like apples compared to number of people total,  $\#\text{who like apples}:\#\text{total}$.

We have many ways of representing ratios (such as with geometric shapes, with words, or using colons such as $23:29$), but there is one way that particularly stands out above the rest for convenience.  We can represent this as a **fraction**, $\frac{23}{29}$.

Two ratios, $a:A$ and $b:B$ are said to be equal whenever there exists a (nonzero) number, $k$ such that $b=a\cdot k$ and $B=A\cdot k$ are both true.  Example:  the ratio $3:6$ is equal to the ratio $6:12$ since $6 = 3\cdot 2$ and $12=6\cdot 2$.  In this notation, we usually denote equality of ratios with a double colon.  $3:6::6:12$, read aloud as "3 is to 6 as 6 is to 12".

Working with numbers and definitions using the colon representation is tiring, and it is easier to define equality for ratios represented as fractions.  With fractions, the bar between the numbers in the ratio acts exactly like division (arguably it **is** division), and two ratios are equal if the numbers that result from division are equal.  Example: $0.5=\frac{3}{6} = \frac{6}{12}=0.5$.

So, given a ratio (such as $\frac{23}{29}$) if you want to express it out of 10 instead, that is asking the question of solving for $X$ in:  $23:29::X:10$, or equivalently $\frac{23}{29}=\frac{X}{10}$.  Using simple algebra, by multiplying both sides by $10$ you get $\frac{23\cdot 10}{29}=X$ which simplifies to $7.9301\approxeq X$, so if 23 people out of 29 like apples, then approximately 7.93 people out of 10 like apples.

In general, given a ratio $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{x}{d}$, you can solve for $x$ by multiplying both sides by $d$ in order to come up with a way to represent the ratio $\frac{a}{b}$ in whatever base $d$ you want.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, those kinds of statistics come from some kind of sample survey, possibly run by a statistical organisation (such as the US Bureau of Labor Statistics or the UK Office of National Statistics) or a market research company (such as Roy Morgan). They will select a sample of people, ask questions of them, and use those to derive the statistics.

The simplest derivation is to assume that the proportion of people who answer in a particular way in the sample is the same as in the population - so if you sample 100 people and 10 of them read the newspaper every day, you could conclude that 1 in 10 people read the newspaper daily.

However, there are a wide variety of methods to improve the quality of such estimates by adjusting for things like having different demographics in the sample compared to the population (e.g. if the sample of 100 people has 70 men and 30 women, it may not be representative of a population that is 50% male), effects of non-response (e.g. if to get your sample of 100 people you actually contacted 150, if you know something about the 50 people who didn't respond you may want to adjust your estimates on the assumption that they may have responded differently to the 100 who actually did respond), differences between the population you selected your sample from and the one you're claiming the estimates relate to, and so forth.

The details of all of this - including ways to select the sample and ways to estimate population characteristics based on sample information - are the basis of survey statistics and survey methodology.